# How to pass commands to gdb from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, interactive-mode

I have launched GDB using subprocess.call methond in python .Can any one help how to pass commands to gdb (like 'info threads') from python script.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module if you want to interact with interactive shells.

But I suggest you to use Python bindings that shipped with gdb.

infothreads.py:

```
import gdb
gdb.execute('info threads')
gdb.execute('continue')
```

Run it using `-x` option of gdb:

```
gdb -x infothreads.py -p 21686
```

Documentation on Python bindings may be found here:
[Python API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html#Python-API)